# Angular show and hide multiple elements

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple accordion menu - display: none display: block.

I'm having difficulty showing and hiding individual elements one by one at the moment when i click one accordion menu ALL accordion hidden menus are displaying. Does any know how i can solve this issue. I am aware I can use bootstrap how i want to custom build this...

Below is snippets of my code.

Angular

```
    $scope.frqToggle = function () {
    $scope.hiddenToggle = !$scope.hiddenToggle;
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-click="frqToggle()" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        Some text goes here 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseOne" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggle}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                    hidden menu goes here 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>

    <div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
             <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE -->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle()" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        some text
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseTwo" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggle}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                SOME TEXT 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>

    <div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE -->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle()" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Q:&nbsp;</strong>What are the key opportunities associated with spirit of place designs in travel-retail and duty-free environments?
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseThree" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggle}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                    <strong>A:&nbsp;</strong>We know that shoppers increasingly want it all. More brands, more stories, more service, more experiences, more convenience and more value. In this very near shopping future the experience of placelessness in airports could induce more yawns than wows.<br><br>

                    Spirit of place helps pivot passengers to shoppers. It can disrupt the traveller’s mindset by revealing the rich bounty of a local story. To be effective it must be a ‘living story’. Meaning it has continuity with the past, represents the present too and grows as the local story evolves.<br><br>

                    Airports with a sense of placelessness will miss an opportunity to seduce expectant passengers to become willing shoppers using a spirit of place.<br><br>

                    <small><strong>13/09/2016&nbsp;|&nbsp;</strong><b>Lewis Allen</b>, Director of Environments, Portland Design</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
```

Comment: What did you expect would happen? You only have one variable that determines whether or not an element is visible or hidden. You would need a separate variable for EACH element you want to hide or show.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle wouldn't it be easier to demonstrate what you mean for individuals that encounter the same experience know how to solve the problem.

Comment: It would be easier for you. You could then just copy and paste and move on with your life. But, I'm asking you to really think about what you have implemented above. What do YOU suspect is wrong with your code? I have just given you a huge clue.

Comment: try not to comment on this thread please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a seperate variable for each element you want to show/hide:

```
$scope.hiddenToggleOne = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleTwo = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleThree = false;
//one fore each ...

$scope.frqToggle = function (toggleElem) {
    toggleElem = !toggleElem;
};
```

You markup:

```
<div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleOne)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        Some text goes here 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseOne" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleOne}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                    hidden menu goes here 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>

    <div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
             <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE -->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleTwo)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        some text
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseTwo" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleTwo}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                SOME TEXT 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>

    <div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default"> <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE -->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleThree)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="future-box-date panel-heading-date">
                    <img src="/assets/FRQs/FRQ-Pointing-Right.png" alt="Arrow" />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>
                        <strong>Q:&nbsp;</strong>What are the key opportunities associated with spirit of place designs in travel-retail and duty-free environments?
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseThree" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleThree}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>
                    <strong>A:&nbsp;</strong>We know that shoppers increasingly want it all. More brands, more stories, more service, more experiences, more convenience and more value. In this very near shopping future the experience of placelessness in airports could induce more yawns than wows.<br><br>

                    Spirit of place helps pivot passengers to shoppers. It can disrupt the traveller’s mindset by revealing the rich bounty of a local story. To be effective it must be a ‘living story’. Meaning it has continuity with the past, represents the present too and grows as the local story evolves.<br><br>

                    Airports with a sense of placelessness will miss an opportunity to seduce expectant passengers to become willing shoppers using a spirit of place.<br><br>

                    <small><strong>13/09/2016&nbsp;|&nbsp;</strong><b>Lewis Allen</b>, Director of Environments, Portland Design</small>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object to maintain which accordion is open. Lets say you have an accordion with 3 menu items that can open. Have an object like this which maintains which menu is open and which is closed.

```
$scope.accordion_visibility = {
  menu_1: true,
  menu_2: false,
  menu_3: false
}
```

Now create a method to toggle the visibility of a menu.

```
$scope.toggleMenuVisibility = function(menu_name){
  $scope.accordion_visibility[menu_name] = !$scope.accordion_visibility[menu_name];
}
```

Now in the view, use ng-show="accordion.menu_1", ng-show="accordion.menu_2" etc on each menu item. Also, add ng-click listener on each like `ng-click="toggleMenuVisibility('menu_1')`", `ng-click="toggleMenuVisibility('menu_2')`" etc on each menu. It should work.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a jsFiddle example ?

Comment: No I think I have elaborated it enough. Maybe you should make a jsFiddle making all the changes I mentioned and I can make corrections in that?

Comment: It's fine I discovered a much better solution, doing the way you mentioned is quite clunky

Answer (score 0):

button 1

```
 <a (click)="iconClick(1)">
    <p style="color:gray;">
      nr 1  Create Documents from Scratch
    </p>
  </a>
```

button 2

```
 <a (click)="iconClick(2)">
        <p style="color:gray;">
         nr 2  Create Documents from Scratch
        </p>
      </a>
```

on text 1

```
      <div class="col-12" *ngIf="icon == 1"></div>
```

on text 2

```
  <div class="col-12" *ngIf="icon == 2"></div>
```

on component

```
  icon = null;
  iconClick(number) {
    this.icon = number;
  }
```